# Is there a way to access a PHP variable's name and use it to get a POST variable of the same name?

Tags: php, post

I know this can't be best practice, but out of curiosity, is there a way to loop through several PHP variables and assign them to a POST variable of the same name?

For example, if I were to need to do something like

```
$var1 = $_POST["var1"]
```

I might be able to loop through all of my variables and do

```
foreach($values_array as &$value) {
    if isset($_POST[valueName($value)]) {
        $value = $_POST[valueName($value)];
    } else {
        $value = "";
    }
}
```

In the end, I'm just not sure what the best way to check and assign a large number of POST values (I'm looking at over 50 right now...). Pointers to correct way would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: i bet there is a php function for that ;)

Comment: This is easy to do, but why?  Trust me this is the wrong approach.  Just use the `$_POST` array as it is much easier just to keep it in the array.

Comment: This is probably not a good idea, unless you have a whitelist to check them off against. Think about what will happen if a hacker tries to overwrite variables that you are using that are not in the form (and which you did not intend would be created this way) - he/she might be able to overwrite a SQL string, for example, and then run arbitrary SQL in your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can use `extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) for a much simpler and safer approach:

```
extract($_POST, EXTR_SKIP); // "Safest" way
```

You can use the `EXTR_IF_EXISTS` flag to only overwrite existing variables, or you could use `EXTR_SKIP` to prevent writing into any variables that already exist (for best safety.) You can also prefix all of the variables:

```
extract($_POST, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'post');
```

Then a `$_POST['variable']` would be available through `$postvariable` - but be wary - for example, you must ensure that none of your PHP variables start with "post"

The normal practice is to leave the `$_POST` variables where they are and access them directly until you begin manipulating, validating, and sanitizing them.

Comment: or just use `extract()`

Comment: How are the keys of $_POST available in the global scope in the first place? Or in the case of a function, in the function scope?

Comment: @Dagon Sure, what are the differences?

Comment: its a single function, no loop, designed *exactly* for this

Comment: Extract offers a second parameter, which may make it less *unsafe* or rather more predictable.

Comment: @Dagon Ah, I see. Added in and wiki'd

Comment: OP, if you do do this, at least wrap it in a function, so all variables created from a form are local. That way you can be careful what other local variables could be overwritten, and to make sure they cannot do any damage if they are maliciously modified.